# Git Overwrite file in master with same file from different branch

Tags: git

In Git, how can I overwrite a file in my ***master*** branch with this same file from a specific branch called **inventory**.

Can I do this to one specific file in my ***inventory*** branch? I accidentally merged the wrong version of a file to master, the correct version is found in inventory branch.

Comment: Do I have to do it manually?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to create another branch - may be called `fix-file-{xyz}` - which branching from master. Then apply the changes on that branch, and merge to master, so you don't need to touch `inventory` branch

Comment: Have you pushed yet?

Comment: Yes sir, I pushed

Comment: Then assuming you're not the only one working on the repo, the only solution is to create a new commit with the correct version of the file in it and repush ASAP. There's a few different ways to do this.

Comment: The simplest would be what (i think) you're calling manual. Checkout the inventory branch, copy the correct file outside the repo, checkout current master branch, replace incorrect file, commit, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways:

1) Manual way:
Let say you have this

```
 > master 
   >> inventory -- file a.js file b.js
```

On `master / a.js` is not latest, and you need to push **only** `a.js` to master.
The easiest way to solve this, is creating new branch, may be call `fix-a.js`

```
> master
  >> inventory -- file a.js file b.js
  >> `fix-a.js` -- same as master
```

Applies the fix on the new branch and push it to master

2) Git way: just use `git checkout source_branch <paths>...`

We can simply give git checkout the name of the feature branch1 and the paths to the specific files that we want to add to our master branch.

```
$ git branch
* master
  inventory

$ git checkout inventory {path-to-a.js}/a.js
$ git commit -m "merge the a.js from inventory branch"
```

**Edit**: I learnt the 1st way by working experience, and learnt the 2nd way by this: https://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/